Expressjs access_token not setting in cookies for 2nd time
Am using JWT and setting cookies from backend to frontend. Am using expressjs and testing API I'm using postman. So every time I call an api at first i update the access token (where i generate new access_token and refresh_token and set it as res.cookie ). Its works fine if i make request or hit api under access_token expire time. But  The problem is it can't find access_token in isAuthenticated function if i call it after access_token expire.
This is my console

My code:

Route.ts

const BlogRoute = express.Router();

BlogRoute.route("/blog/all-blogs").get(getAllBlogPosts);

BlogRoute.route("/blog/single/:blogID")
    .get(getSingleBlogPost)
    .put(
        updateAccessToken,
        isAuthenticated,
        authorizeRoles("admin"),
        multerUploads.array("files"),
        updateBlogPost
    )


updateAccessToken func

export const updateAccessToken = CatchAsyncError(
    async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
        const { refresh_token } = req.cookies;
        console.log("updateAccessToken: Received cookies", req.cookies);

        if (!refresh_token) {
            return next(new ErrorHandler("Refresh token is missing", 401));
        }

        try {
            const decoded = jwt.verify(
                refresh_token,
                process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET as string
            ) as JwtPayload;

            const user = await UserModel.findById(decoded._id);

            if (!user) {
                return next(new ErrorHandler("User not found", 404));
            }

            const newAccessToken = user.signAccessToken();
            const newRefreshToken = user.signRefreshToken();

            res.cookie("access_token", newAccessToken, accessTokenOptions);
            res.cookie("refresh_token", newRefreshToken, refreshTokenOptions);
            console.log("updateAccessToken: New tokens set");

            req.user = user;
        } catch (error) {
            return next(new ErrorHandler("Invalid refresh token", 401));
        }

        next();
    }
);

As you can see on avobe i set up the cookies before calling next()

isAuthenticated func

export const isAuthenticated = CatchAsyncError(
    async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
        const { access_token } = req.cookies;
        console.log("isAuthenticated: Received cookies", req.cookies);

        if (!access_token) {
            return next(
                new ErrorHandler("Please login to access this resource", 400)
            );
        }

        try {
            const decoded: any = jwt.verify(
                access_token,
                process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET as string
            );

            if (!decoded) {
                return next(new ErrorHandler("Invalid access_token", 400));
            }

            const user = await UserModel.findById(decoded._id);

            if (!user) {
                return next(new ErrorHandler("User not found", 404));
            }

            (req as any).user = user;
        } catch (error) {
            return next(
                new ErrorHandler("IsAuthenticated Error in Auth.ts", 400)
            );
        }

        next();
    }
);

** But Here i cant get the access_token **
In postman I get this response


NOTE: Also theres a another things. After i get this response in postman my access_token are in there. I think is that because i need to make it some dealy or wait for it to set cookies properly then move to another?. Normaly(if i make req within expire time) the access_token go top and refresh_token goes down. But when i get this error access_token missing and Please login... the refresh_token goes top and new access_token get down .

I try to debug and as you can see in console. this same system i was used for radis database. but now am not using it. am just fetching from mongodb. And also as in postman i get the updated access_token but dont know why isAuthenticated cant read it.
So am expecting my isAuthenticated can read my access_token. I mean access_token should be there in isAuthenticated.

I figured out this solution and it works for me but not sure why I am still not getting the access_token in isAuthenticated func. If anyone can explain that it will be better. Thank You.
The solution is

1| Propagate the new access token to the next middleware by setting it
in req.cookies or req.headers.
2| Directly set the updated access token in the request headers or
cookies after refreshing it in the updateAccessToken middleware.

So in my code I did
    console.log("Response Headers:", res.getHeaders(), "\n \n \n");

    req.user = user;

    // Set the new access token in the request object
    req.cookies.access_token = newAccessToken;

    next();

Even though I console.log the headers and I get the access_token

